# pyspark exploding json into dataframe rows

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this json which I want to use to create the columns in dataframe:

json:

```
{
                    "Version": "V1",
                    "Fruit1": {
                        "Apple": 60.0,
                        "Orange": 60.0,
                        "Melon": 60.0
                    },
                    "Fruit2": {
                        "Strawberry": 40.0,
                        "Orange": 60.0,
                        "Melon": 40.0
                    },
                    "Fruit3": {
                        "Apple": 90.0,
                        "Orange": 90.0,
                        "Melon": 95.0
                    }
                }
```

The number of layers for Fruit could increase or decrease, like there can be another layer Fruit4 or there can only be one layer in this json which is Fruit1. The number of fruit names are fixed. I want to construct this dataframe out of it. Anyy help would be really appreciated.

```
Version  Name    Apple  Orange  Melon  Strawberry
V1       Fruit1  60     60      60     null
V1       Fruit2  null   60      40     40
V1       Fruit3  90     90      95     null
```

Comment: where and how are the json stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the jsons are stored in a file, you can read it using `spark.read.json()` and further process it.

I've added a new row (a new json) with `version="V2"` and few additional fruits to your example data, and the same is stored in a file.

Reading the json file (*source at the bottom*)

```py
multiline_json_sdf = spark.read. \
    option('multiLine', 'true'). \
    json('./path/to/file_with_jsons.json')

# +------------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------+-------+
# |Fruit1            |Fruit2            |Fruit3                  |Fruit4            |Version|
# +------------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------+-------+
# |{60.0, 60.0, 60.0}|{40.0, 60.0, 40.0}|{90.0, 95.0, 90.0, null}|null              |V1     |
# |{60.0, 60.0, 60.0}|{40.0, 60.0, 40.0}|{90.0, 95.0, null, 90.0}|{90.0, 95.0, 90.0}|V2     |
# +------------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------+-------+

# root
#  |-- Fruit1: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Apple: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Melon: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Orange: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- Fruit2: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Melon: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Orange: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Strawberry: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- Fruit3: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Apple: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Melon: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Orange: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Squash: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- Fruit4: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Apple: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Banana: double (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- Orange: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- Version: string (nullable = true)
```

My approach is to flatten the data, and then unpivot it so that all column values are in rows against their fruit names. The long data can then be pivoted as per requirements.

Flatten the data

```py
# extract fruit columns and their struct fields
fruit_cols = [k for k in multiline_json_sdf.columns if 'fruit' in k.lower()]
fruitcol_struct_fields = {}

for fruit in fruit_cols:
    # dict[fruit column name] = [(old field name, fruit column name + old field name, ...]
    fruitcol_struct_fields[fruit] = [(k, fruit + '_' + k) for k in multiline_json_sdf.select(func.col('{0}.*'.format(fruit))).columns]

# use the aforementioned to iterate and create new columns in dataframe
flattened_json_sdf = multiline_json_sdf. \
    select('version',
           *reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [[func.col('{}.'.format(fruit)+k[0]).alias(k[1])
                                         for k in fruitcol_struct_fields[fruit]]
                                        for fruit in fruit_cols]
                   )
           )

# +-------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+---+-------------+-------------+
# |version|Fruit1_Apple|Fruit1_Melon|Fruit1_Orange|Fruit2_Melon|...|Fruit4_Banana|Fruit4_Orange|
# +-------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+---+-------------+-------------+
# |V1     |60.0        |60.0        |60.0         |40.0        |...|null         |null         |
# |V2     |60.0        |60.0        |60.0         |40.0        |...|95.0         |90.0         |
# +-------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+---+-------------+-------------+
```

The list comprehension within the `select` creates new columns using the struct fields - `fruit1.Apple as fruit1_Apple, ..., fruit4.Orange as fruit4_Orange`.

This flattened data can be transposed down and then pivoted back using the fruit names.

```py
flattened_json_sdf. \
    withColumn('fruit_struct_arr',
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('key'), func.col(k).alias('val')) 
                            for k in flattened_json_sdf.columns if k != 'version']
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('version', 'inline(fruit_struct_arr)'). \
    withColumn('key_split', func.split('key', '_')). \
    withColumn('name', func.col('key_split')[0]). \
    withColumn('fruit_to_pivot', func.col('key_split')[1]). \
    groupBy('version', 'name'). \
    pivot('fruit_to_pivot'). \
    agg(func.first('val')). \
    show()

# +-------+------+-----+------+-----+------+------+----------+
# |version|  name|Apple|Banana|Melon|Orange|Squash|Strawberry|
# +-------+------+-----+------+-----+------+------+----------+
# |     V1|Fruit2| null|  null| 40.0|  60.0|  null|      40.0|
# |     V1|Fruit1| 60.0|  null| 60.0|  60.0|  null|      null|
# |     V1|Fruit4| null|  null| null|  null|  null|      null|
# |     V2|Fruit4| 90.0|  95.0| null|  90.0|  null|      null|
# |     V1|Fruit3| 90.0|  null| 95.0|  90.0|  null|      null|
# |     V2|Fruit2| null|  null| 40.0|  60.0|  null|      40.0|
# |     V2|Fruit1| 60.0|  null| 60.0|  60.0|  null|      null|
# |     V2|Fruit3| 90.0|  null| 95.0|  null|  90.0|      null|
# +-------+------+-----+------+-----+------+------+----------+
```

`fruit_struct_arr` is an array of column structs that has the column name as `"key"` and column value as `"val"`. Use the SQL `inline()` function to explode it and create 2 columns - `key, val` - along with the `version` provided in the `selectExpr`. Use the newly created `key` column to extract the fruit names and the identifier - `split` can be used with `"_"` as delimiter. Once extracted, they can be pivoted to get the required data format.

---

source JSON file

```
[{
    "Version": "V1",
    "Fruit1": {
        "Apple": 60.0,
        "Orange": 60.0,
        "Melon": 60.0
    },
    "Fruit2": {
        "Strawberry": 40.0,
        "Orange": 60.0,
        "Melon": 40.0
    },
    "Fruit3": {
        "Apple": 90.0,
        "Orange": 90.0,
        "Melon": 95.0
    }
},
{
    "Version": "V2",
    "Fruit1": {
        "Apple": 60.0,
        "Orange": 60.0,
        "Melon": 60.0
    },
    "Fruit2": {
        "Strawberry": 40.0,
        "Orange": 60.0,
        "Melon": 40.0
    },
    "Fruit3": {
        "Apple": 90.0,
        "Squash": 90.0,
        "Melon": 95.0
    },
    "Fruit4": {
        "Apple": 90.0,
        "Orange": 90.0,
        "Banana": 95.0
    }
}]
```

```py
print(fruit_cols)
# ['Fruit1', 'Fruit2', 'Fruit3', 'Fruit4']

print(fruitcol_struct_fields)
# {'Fruit1': [('Apple', 'Fruit1_Apple'),
#   ('Melon', 'Fruit1_Melon'),
#   ('Orange', 'Fruit1_Orange')],
#  'Fruit2': [('Melon', 'Fruit2_Melon'),
#   ('Orange', 'Fruit2_Orange'),
#   ('Strawberry', 'Fruit2_Strawberry')],
#  'Fruit3': [('Apple', 'Fruit3_Apple'),
#   ('Melon', 'Fruit3_Melon'),
#   ('Orange', 'Fruit3_Orange'),
#   ('Squash', 'Fruit3_Squash')],
#  'Fruit4': [('Apple', 'Fruit4_Apple'),
#   ('Banana', 'Fruit4_Banana'),
#   ('Orange', 'Fruit4_Orange')]}
```

```py
flattened_json_sdf. \
    withColumn('fruit_struct_arr',
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('key'), func.col(k).alias('val')) 
                            for k in flattened_json_sdf.columns if k != 'version']
                          )
               ). \
    select('version', 'fruit_struct_arr'). \
    show(truncate=50)

# +-------+--------------------------------------------------+
# |version|                                  fruit_struct_arr|
# +-------+--------------------------------------------------+
# |     V1|[{Fruit1_Apple, 60.0}, {Fruit1_Melon, 60.0}, {F...|
# |     V2|[{Fruit1_Apple, 60.0}, {Fruit1_Melon, 60.0}, {F...|
# +-------+--------------------------------------------------+

# root
#  |-- version: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- fruit_struct_arr: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |    |-- val: double (nullable = true)
```

```py
flattened_json_sdf. \
    withColumn('fruit_struct_arr',
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('key'), func.col(k).alias('val')) 
                            for k in flattened_json_sdf.columns if k != 'version']
                          )
               ). \
    selectExpr('version', 'inline(fruit_struct_arr)'). \
    withColumn('key_split', func.split('key', '_')). \
    withColumn('name', func.col('key_split')[0]). \
    withColumn('fruit_to_pivot', func.col('key_split')[1]). \
    show(5)

# +-------+-------------+----+----------------+------+--------------+
# |version|          key| val|       key_split|  name|fruit_to_pivot|
# +-------+-------------+----+----------------+------+--------------+
# |     V1| Fruit1_Apple|60.0| [Fruit1, Apple]|Fruit1|         Apple|
# |     V1| Fruit1_Melon|60.0| [Fruit1, Melon]|Fruit1|         Melon|
# |     V1|Fruit1_Orange|60.0|[Fruit1, Orange]|Fruit1|        Orange|
# |     V1| Fruit2_Melon|40.0| [Fruit2, Melon]|Fruit2|         Melon|
# |     V1|Fruit2_Orange|60.0|[Fruit2, Orange]|Fruit2|        Orange|
# +-------+-------------+----+----------------+------+--------------+
# only showing top 5 rows
```